# Why is it impossible to find a parametrization of the circle such that the line integral of $\frac {1}{z}$ is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Ullrich's complex analysis:

[image]

So we all know this integral is nonzero and if we double the "speed" of our parametrization given above, the value of the integral is doubled , so the value does depend on parametrization, but how do we know that we can never find a parametrization such that this integral will not be 0?

(I will assume all curves are piecewise smooth).

Comment: The value of the integral is not doubled. The value of a contour integral is invariant of the parametrisation used

Comment: If you double the speed so that you go around the circle twice, it is doubled, but doubling the speed is not the important thing. If you defined $\gamma$ on $[0,4\pi]$ at the same speed it would also double. The key is the number of times you go around the circle in the path, not the speed.

Comment: what do you mean by parametrization? technically a parametrization should give a unique point on the curve for each $t$ except at self intersection so at ends for a Jordan curve; going twice with $e^{2it}$ is not really a parametrization of the circle, but if you allow that who stops you to go once counterclockwise and once clockwise (eg use $e^{2it}, 0 \le t \le \pi, e^{-2it}, \pi \le t \le 2\pi$ and then your integral should be zero; if the parametrization is $1-1$ except at ends, the integral never changes except possibly in sign if you change orientation as others noted

Comment: So if you define $\gamma_2$ on $[0,\pi]$ as $\gamma_2(t)=\gamma(2t),$ a true reparameterization, you get the same result, not twice the result.

Comment: A re-parameterization of $\gamma;[a,b]\to X$ is a map $\rho:[c,d]\to X$ defined as $\rho=\gamma\circ p,$ where $p$ is a bijective continuous map: $p:[c,d]\to[a,b]$ with $p(c)=a, p(d)=b.$